# How to implement distributed DB concept in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I have a centralized db now at a location which is shared via network to other two locations. The current problem is Data fetched at remote locations by Network is slower and i want to implement Distributed db concept.
PS: I cannot use cloud tech due to some reasons.

Can somebody please elaborate on this and sugggest me a best distributed db implementation method for MySQL.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the latency between the nodes?  Is it Reads?  or Writes?  that are the main problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try MySQL's GROUP REPLICATION, as it keeps the READ requests to local server which reduce the READ latency. (WRITE-based requests still have to go through the network. ) Depending on your scenarios, if the other two locations require READ-ONLY privilege, then the Single-Primary GROUP REPLICATION shall suffice. Otherwise, the Multiple-Primary GROUP REPLICATION is the way to go , which grants all locations READ-WRITE privilege. It's a long topic, and the deployment isn't entirely friendly though if you have no prior experience in said realm. I would suggest checking MySQL reference manual or search the related tutorials online. As it's considered a DBA's job, discussing non-developer-based topics are not encourged at stackoverflow.

Comment: That's a good solution for MySQL.  For MariaDB, see Galera; it is 'similar' to MySQL's Group Replication.